# Creating several arrays of different but fixed sizes

Tags: arrays, rust

Is it possible to create arrays of a technically variable size but that is known at compile time ? More precisely, I want to do something like this :

```
fn main() {
    for n in 1..5 {
        let array: [i32; n] = [0; n];
        // Do stuff with array
    }
}
```

This code does not compile, but i feel like it should be possible to do, since the only thing the `for` loop could be unraveled by the compiler, like this :

```
fn main() {
    let array: [i32; 1] = [0; 1];
    let array: [i32; 2] = [0; 2];
    let array: [i32; 3] = [0; 3];
    let array: [i32; 4] = [0; 4];
    let array: [i32; 5] = [0; 5];
}
```

which compiles and does what I want, but is very repetitive

I could use vectors or other data structures, but then I would have variables in the heap, and I don't think that I should use the heap just because i use my arrays in a `for` loop

Comment: Maybe the [unroll](https://docs.rs/unroll/latest/unroll/) crate could help? I haven’t tried compiling it yet

Comment: Or you could make a procedural macro to unroll the loop, though that seems like an annoyingly involved solution for this problem

Comment: I haven't tested your solutions yet, but even if they worked, I agree with you that they seem to be far too convoluted solutions for what I think is a simple problem

Comment: @clino: This is a problem that looks simple but it is not, because you are using a run-time construt (a `for`-loop) to build a compile time object (a type), in a language without runtime reflection of any kind. Currently the only way to do this kind of _metaprogramming_ is using macros; or writing a `build.rs` that generates the source code. Or writing it by hand, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I thought that there was a way to tell the compiler "this iterator is a constant, so at compile time, if unwrapping the associated loop makes the code valid, then do it"

Comment: @clino Even detecting that this iterator can be unrolled is very hard to generally impossible (without special-casing slices, which I see no good reason to).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: I guess you could add a new syntax to avoid the auto detection, something like `for const x in 1..5` requiring a const range and guaranteeing that `x` is a  compiler constant.

Comment: You could also make an array of the maximum size, then use a slice to reduce its size: `let array = [0; 5]; let array = &array[..i];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the [unroll](https://docs.rs/unroll/latest/unroll/) crate.

```
#[unroll::unroll_for_loops]
fn main() {
    for n in 1..5 {
        let array: [i32; n] = [0; n];
        println!("{:?}", array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is looking for a constant when specifying array size. Since `n` is variable, it has issue. You are still wanting a variable-sized array, which I believe would need to be allocated on the heap if you're using standard types.

In unstable Rust, there is a feature called "[unsized_locals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html)", which can be enabled to provide a variable-sized array allocated on the stack, but this is not yet implemented in the stable version of the language.

There is also a crate called "[heapless](https://github.com/japaric/heapless)" that does what you're looking for.